# How do you set your local DNS name on OS X (so you can reach it from a Windows box?)

Tags: macos, networking, dns, dhcp

On my work network, all the PCs  get a local `machine01.abc.com`-style DNS name. Is there a way to do that on OS X? In a way that machines without Bonjour can see it? (The .local domain name won't work for this, right?)

I'm looking into at Directory Utility, `scutil`, and the advanced Network prefs, but so far no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an 'A' record containing your Mac's IP address on the DNS server for `abc.com`, or at least the non-canonical DNS server serving your local network. It can't be done on the Mac itself - that's what's so clever about Bonjour hostnames; it's a multicast DNS system, which allows peers to set their own hostname.

Answer (score 2):

How do the Windows machines get their names? Did you manually configure your DNS server with a bunch of `machineXX.abc.com` A records (in DNS terminology, an "A" record is an Address record which maps a host name to an IPv4 address), or do they register themselves with a WINS server (perhaps one running on your local Windows 200x Server that's acting as a Windows or Active Directory domain controller)?

If you did the DNS server thing, then go to your DNS server and add an A record for your Mac.

If your name registrations and name lookups are happening via a WINS server, you can go to "System Preferences > Network > Ethernet > Advanced... > WINS" to configure your Mac to register a name with the same WINS servers that your PCs use.

If that doesn't work, then you might be using legacy Windows "NetBIOS Name Service", which is a local LAN broadcast-based name service protocol. Try going to "System Preferences > Sharing" and enabling (checking) File Sharing, then from there go to "Options..." and enable "Share files and folders using SMB (Windows)". That will launch Mac OS X's built-in version of Samba's `smbd(8)` and `nmbd(8)` daemons, which should allow your Mac to advertise its name via NetBIOS Name Service.

Comment: If I use the File Sharing method, how does the computer name in the Sharing preference pane translate into a DNS name? Does it just get added as mycomputer.abc.com?

Comment: @zekel That's a little beyond my knowledge of NetBIOS Name Service. I *believe* I've used FQDNs with NetBIOS Name Service in the past, but I mostly just use unqualified host names when I'm stuck with NetBIOS Name Service only.